# Exchange Online Migration set msExchMailboxGuid to null with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

We are migrating from GCC to GCC-High. Several years ago we migrated from Exchange on-prem to Exchange Online.  Now all the legacy mailboxes that were migrated from on-prem to EXO will not migrate to GCC-High EXO. I have read a lot about this issue and the going suggestion is to use AAD Connect to set the msExchMailboxGuid to NULL. Our migration partner is suggesting we may be able to run powershell and set msExchMailboxGuid to Null. I am not sure what that will do.  We do not have any mailboxes on-prem anymore so the AAD Connect suggestion doesn't really match 100%

What happens if I delete the msExchMailboxGuid with powershell?